# Binding same function to window resize event with different arguments

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize, bind

I am making a simple JS plugin to resize objects vertically.  It works fine until the resize event - wherein `$flexParent` appears to be being set as the last `$flexParent` in the initial `.each()` function for all of the binds.  So for three 'flexParents' being passed to the plugin, only the last one is getting acted on on the resize event; just 3 times. Obviously I'm misunderstanding binding here but I'd be grateful of some clarity!

```
(function($){
    $.fn.flexHeight = function(options) {

        if (!options){options = {};}
        var settings = $.extend({
            boxes: false
        }, options);

        function main(flexParent) {
            var $flexParent = flexParent;
            if (settings.boxes) {
                $children = $flexParent.find(settings.boxes);
            } else {
                $children = $flexParent.children
            }
            var maxHeight = 0;

            $children.each(function() {
                $(this).height('auto');
            });

            $children.each(function() {
                maxHeight = maxHeight > $(this).outerHeight(false) ? maxHeight : $(this).outerHeight(false);
            });

            $children.each(function() {
                $(this).height(maxHeight);
            });
        }

        return this.each(function() {
            $flexParent = $(this);
            main($flexParent);
            $(window).resize(function() {
                main($flexParent);
            });
        });
    }   
}(jQuery));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$flexParent` is declared as a global variable, so it's shared between function calls. By the time the window resize callback gets called, the global $flexParent variable will point to the last element.

Change your code to:

```
  return this.each(function() {
        var $flexParent = $(this); // <-- added var here
        main($flexParent);
        $(window).resize(function() {
            main($flexParent);
        });
    });
```

This makes the `$flexParent` local to the function passed to each, so there will be one variable for each element.